# Display KMZ/KML file google earth online

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, kendo-ui, kmz

I have a kmz file which I need to display in google earth on the browser.

I am using AngularJS, Kendo UI to do this.

I tried to unzip the KMZ file to extract the KML file but does not seem to work. Can someone point me in the correct direction please?

Answer (score 0):

[Google Earth API/plugin](https://developers.google.com/earth/) has been deprecated due to browsers removing support for NPAPI plugins for security reasons.

To view KML and KMZ files in web-based applications, you can use [CesiumJS](https://cesiumjs.org/), Google Maps API, or a variety of other map libraries. Cesium can be used to create 3-D globe or 2-D map-based views.

In Cesium its 1 line of code:

```
viewer.dataSources.add(
  Cesium.KmlDataSource.load('../../SampleData/facilities.kmz')
);
```

You can find an online example that loads KMZ files onto a 3D globe.
Navigate to *DataSource* tab in the [Gallery](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/index.html%3Cbr%3E) for the KML example.

Cesium has tutorials on migrating from Google Earth API to Cesium.
http://cesiumjs.org/for-google-earth-developers.html